# No sound from speakers when headphones plugged in even after switching output device, (Ubuntu 20.04, Linux Mint 20, Fedora 32)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

So i have tried to use pavucontrol, where i can see "Line Out (plugged in)" and "Headphones (plugged in)". My problem is that the sound is output to the headphones when they are plugged in and when i try to switch output to the line out on the speakers - there is no sound at all. BUT(!) if i unplug the headphones then the sound in the speakers appears. The same PC with Windows 10 on board can switch devices with no problem. How can I fix it for Linux systems?

p.s. I've read several similar topics, but in them the cases are slightly different

Comment: There could be either software configuration problems, or hardware driver problems. With your question it's not really possible to guess, but I would tend toward hardware since it's multiple distributions. So to have any chance of any answer helping, you should do some research on your hardware and state in the question what it is.

Comment: @A.B Not hardware since it works with Windows. And I have the same issue with completely different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "issue".
Open terminal and launch `alsamix`
then search for `<Auto-Mut>` , probably it is "Enabled", you must switch to Disabled.
Finally you need save the alsamixer state `sudo alsactl store`.